# Newton's Second Law and External Forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I was reading about Newton's Second Law, and I saw that only external forces can move a body. However, when animals and people walk, when rockets launch, and cars drive, isn't it an internal force that causes a change? How do these things fit into Newton's Second Law?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has to be careful how to define what is the system under consideration so as to know what is internal and external. When animals and people walk, they are acted on by an external force - the friction between their feet and the ground. With rockets, hot gases are forced out the back. They exert an equal and opposite, now external, force on the rocket.